# Iterating over an ArrayList with an array

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I'm iterating over the index of a List with an array. This line of code

```
score += SquareTable[index.get(i)];
```

generates an error and I'm out of ideas on how to fix it.

```
@Override
public int evaluatePieceScore() {

    int score = 0;
    List<Piece> index = chessgame.getPieces();

    
    for (Piece piece : this.chessgame.getPieces()){
        if(piece.getColor() == Piece.YELLOW_COLOR){
            
            
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_PAWN),   PawnSquareTable);
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_KNIGHT), KnightSquareTable);
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_BISHOP), BishopSquareTable);               
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_ROOK),   RookSquareTable);
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_QUEEN),  QueenSquareTable);
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_KING),   KingMiddleGameSquareTable);
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_KING),   KingEndGameSquareTable);
            
            
        }else if(piece.getColor() == Piece.BROWN_COLOR){
            
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_PAWN),   reverse(PawnSquareTable));
            score += this.CalculateScore(index ,getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_KNIGHT), reverse(KnightSquareTable));
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_BISHOP), reverse(BishopSquareTable));              
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_ROOK),   reverse(RookSquareTable));
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_QUEEN),  reverse(QueenSquareTable));
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_KING),   reverse(KingMiddleGameSquareTable));
            score += this.CalculateScore(index, getPieceValue(Piece.TYPE_KING),   reverse(KingEndGameSquareTable));
            
            
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown piece color found: "+piece.getColor());
        }
    }       
    return score;
}

public int CalculateScore(List<Piece> index, int pieceValue, int[] SquareTable ){
    
    int score = pieceValue * index.size();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++){
        score += SquareTable[index.get(i)];
    }
    
    return score;
}
```

Comment: Need error stacktrace.

Comment: please can you elaborate more

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: it bring up this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Piece to int".

Comment: You'll have provide more code for us to help you.

Comment: you need to provide more code and explanation

Comment: and that error is due to the you passing piece type argument in the array

Comment: i have updated the question code

Comment: yeah is there anyway i can pass a piece type into an array

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `SquareTable` array using a `Piece` instance (from List) instead of an `int`.

```
public int CalculateScore(List<Piece> index, int pieceValue, int[] SquareTable ){

 SquareTable[index.get(i)];
```

Comment: Well, that cannot work. Arrays can only be accessed by `int` index.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.get(i) gives you an object of type `Piece`
```

and according to this code

`int[] SquareTable`,

`SquareTable` accepts type `int`

This is what is giving you the `TypeMismatchError`

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up collections in the implementation which can look like

```
public int CalculateScore(List<Piece> index, int pieceValue, int[] SquareTable ){    
    int score = pieceValue * index.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < SquareTable.size(); i++){
        score += getPieceValue(index.get(SquareTable[i]));
    }

    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

index.get(I) fetches you Piece objects, So you cannot use it to access elements in an array.